# pyinstaller e webdriver-manager com problemas

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ssl, pyinstaller

Criei um aplicativo que usa webdriver-manager e gostaria de torná-lo um único arquivo com pyinstaller, mas está apresentando um erro.

Configurei um cenário de teste para exemplificar meu problema.

```
(base) C:\python>python -m venv test_pyinstaller
(base) C:\python>cd test_pyinstaller
(base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller>Scripts\activate.bat
(test_pyinstaller) (base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller>pip install webdriver-manager pyinstaller
```

Criei um script bem simples para mostrar o erro

```
test.py    
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
print(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

rodando no venv funciona bem

```
(test_pyinstaller) (base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller>python test.py

[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 96.0.4664
[WDM] - Get LATEST chromedriver version for 96.0.4664 google-chrome
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\user\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
C:\Users\user\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\96.0.4664.45\chromedriver.exe
```

Quando crio o arquivo executável ele apresenta problemas

```
(test_pyinstaller) (base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller>pyinstaller --onefile test.py
(test_pyinstaller) (base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller>cd dist
(test_pyinstaller) (base) C:\python\test_pyinstaller\dist>test.exe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_96.0.4664 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 37, in install
  File "webdriver_manager\core\manager.py", line 29, in _get_driver_path
  File "webdriver_manager\core\driver_cache.py", line 95, in find_driver
  File "webdriver_manager\core\driver.py", line 42, in get_version
  File "webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 44, in get_latest_release_version
  File "webdriver_manager\core\http.py", line 32, in get
  File "requests\api.py", line 73, in get
  File "requests\api.py", line 59, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_96.0.4664 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
[31840] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

Tentei adicionar as dlls em **libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll** e **libssl-1_1-x64.dll** dentro da pasta do projeto e editei o arquivo **test.spec**, e adicionei as dlls dentro,

```
binaries=[('libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll', '.'), ('libssl-1_1-x64.dll', '.')],
```

mas não funcionou. Eu gostaria de poder usar o executável em qualquer computador

Answer (score -1):

É só atualizar a versão do pyinstaller que funciona.
Execute o comando abaixo para fazer a atualização.

pip install -U pyinstaller

Comment: Obs.: depois da atualização é necessário recompilar o programa

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).